# Kafka Streams mapping KTable value into separate values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Stream App that reads a single topic as a `KTable`, transforms each element into `0-n` elements and writes all of them to another topic. The flow looks like this (simplified by quite a bit):

```
('a', '123') -> ('a', '1,2,3') -> ('a1', '1'), ('a2', '2'), ('a3', '3')
```

Is this doable using Kafka Stream DSL? All topics in use are `compact`, therefore I want to simulate a table and never get rid of old values.

**tl;dr;** how to transform a message into multiple messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can express this with the DSL. But it's rather simple to do this with Processor API:

```java
builder.stream("input-topic").transform(...).to("output-topic");
```

You attach a key-value store to your `transform()` and do the following for each input record:

1. check if there is a corresponding key-value pair in the store

   - if yes (ie, `store.get()!=null`), take the old value from the store and split it; replace the value for each "split record" with `null` and emit all those records
2. if input record `value!=null`, put the input record as-is to the store and split the input record and emit the individual output records
3. if input record `value==null`, delete `key` from the store

Check out the docs for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration